# AS3 game character only shoots in one direction

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a top down shooter game and so far my character can move and can shoot when mouse is click. But it will only shoot to the right and not where my cursor is pointing. How do i fix this?

Here's the bullet code in the main class:

```
      public var bulletList:Array = [];

      stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet, false, 0, true);
      stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

  public function shootBullet(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(stage, harold.x, harold.y, harold.rotation);
        bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved, false, 0, true); 
        bulletList.push(bullet);
        stage.addChild(bullet);
    }

    public function loop(e:Event):void 
    {
        if(bulletList.length > 0)
        {
            for(var i:int = bulletList.length-1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                bulletList[i].loop(); 
            }
        }
    }

    public function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved); 
        bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget),1);
    }
```

Here is the code in my Bullet Class:

```
   package
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip
  {
    private var stageRef:Stage; 
    private var speed:Number = 10; 
    private var xVel:Number = 0; 
    private var yVel:Number = 0; 
    private var rotationInRadians = 0; 

    public function Bullet(stageRef:Stage, X:int, Y:int, rotationInDegrees:Number):void
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
    }

    public function loop():void
    {
        xVel = Math.cos(rotationInRadians) * speed; 
        yVel = Math.sin(rotationInRadians) * speed; 

        x += xVel; 
        y += yVel;


        if(x > stageRef.stageWidth || x < 0 || y > stageRef.stageHeight || y < 0)
            {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to assign `rotationInRadians` in your constructor:

```
this.rotationInRadians = rotationInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
```

BTW, unless you want the bullet to be able to change direction during flight, you don't need to calculate the `xVel` and `yVel` each `loop()`, you can just calculate it in the constructor, store it, then update the `x` and `y` each `loop()`.

Comment: First, my formula was backwards, `(180 / Math.PI)` would convert radians to degrees, but you need `(Math.PI / 180)` to convert degrees to radians. I fixed my answer. Second, if you are still only shooting rightward I would check the value of `rotationInDegrees` to see if it's always 0. The code you posted depends on `harold.rotation` pointing in the direction you want to shoot the bullet, but the code you posted doesn't show that value ever being set.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. As said by Aaron, you should compute rotationInRadians in the constructor, altought the real formula is `this.rotationInRadians = rotationInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);`
2. You should make rotationInRadians a number, that is `private var rotationInRadians:Number;`
3. Are you aware displayObject has a getter/setter for rotation? In other words: harold.rotation is a property in harold object or is it referencing to said getter?

I think thats pretty much it.

Comment: re: 1 -- oops, good catch, I am a bit dyslexic sometimes :) Fixed my answer, for the record I had `(180 / Math.PI)` which would convert radians to degrees, instead of `(Math.PI / 180)` to convert degrees to radians as needed here.